The wrong categorization of geographic location of 中部六省
The recent news of China about the inspection made by President Xi Jinping to Shandong Province and the instruction he made for the development of the central six provinces or 中部六省, covers 河南，山西，湖南，湖北，安徽，江西， but historically, 山西 is in Northern China华北，whereas江西 and 安徽 are in Eastern China华东, for example, when people talk about 华东五校 or the most previleged top 5 universities in Eastern China, they include 中国科学技术大学 that is located in Heifei, Anhui Province.
Another point is 陕西, which is the geographically central region of China, is excluded from the central region.
What is more, 广西 as one of the 华南F3 that also include 广东and 海南, is now part of the Southwestern region of China.
It is a little confusing, isn't it?

So, what is your question?

@WayneCheah The last sentence of the post is my question, with a clear question mark attached, as everybody can see.

"A wrong categorisation of geographic location 中部六省...is a little confusing, isn't it?" is not a real question, and the body of this post is poorly written. A real question has a title which sounds something like: "Is 中部六省 considered to cover 山西, 江西, and 安徽?" and the body of your question should contain a citation of Chinese literature (preferably a geography/history textbook or journal article) which indicates otherwise, then your question should end with a citation to the "recent news of China about the inspection", then "why does XYZ news article imply that 中部六省 includes 山西, 江西, and 安徽"?

I guess "中部六省" refers to their combined geographic location, which is located near "the center" of the more populated and economically developed provinces.


You have included Shaanxi, to make them 7 provinces.

Good catch. The map is updated.
